# Internal error: Range error for a test calling a large number

Tags: ruby, math

I am getting an error:

> Internal error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

For this method:

```
def perfect_square(i)
  a = Math.sqrt(5*(i**2)+4)
  b = Math.sqrt(5*(i**2)-4)

  ac = a.ceil
  bc = b.ceil

  if a**2 == ac**2 || b**2 == bc**2
    true
  else
    false
  end
end

puts perfect_square(927372692193078999171)
```

I am assuming the error is because in this example `i` is a really big number and therefore is the method is unable to process? All my other tests (below) are returning true, so I am not sure why the test above is not working.

```
perfect_square(2)        #=> true
perfect_square(10946)    #=> true
perfect_square(6765+100) #=> false
```

Comment: I don't get that error when I run your program with that number. And what's up with the `is_fibonacci?` examples?

Comment: What's this `is_fibonacci?` calls you threw in at the end of your question without comment? :) That is probably causing the call stack error.

Comment: Did you write `is_fibonacci?`? Did you use a recursive implementation? You may have blown the stack with your implementation.

Comment: Oh my bad, I changed the method name and forgot to change the tests. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Can’t reproduce the error with any of the examples. What Ruby version are you using (what’s the full output of `ruby -v`)?

Comment: This is interesting, I ran the code in mac terminal and it worked fine, but when I use repl.it: http://repl.it/OQn it either doesn't complete the program because its taking too long or it gives the error. Actually when I try to run it in repl.it it gives different errors at different times. Weird. Lost cause?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. I just needed to require 'bigdecimal' for it to work and also modify a few of the methods to work with bigdecimal:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

def perfect_square(i)

    i = BigDecimal.new(i) #creates a object for bigdecimals

    a= (5*(i**2) +4).sqrt(0) #sqrt method for big decimal
    b= (5*(i**2) -4).sqrt(0) #sqrt method for big decimal
    return (a == a.round || b == b.round) #boolean
end
```